# Target Parent Div with child Div class with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

i have this code :
what i need is target the first `div.General` with using the child `div.myyyy-classs` , of course without using any ID

```
<div class="General">
<div class="">hello</div>
<div class="">hello</div>
<div class="">hello</div>
</div>

<div class="myyyy-classs">hello</div>


<div class="General">
<div class="none">hello</div>
<div class="none">hello</div>
<div class="none">hello</div>
<div class="none">hello</div>
</div>
```

what i done is

```
$("#Template1").click(function(){
     $(".myyyy-classs").closest(".General").html("Its woking")  
});
```

Comment: And what's the problem, that works just fine as long as you've added jQuery, have an element to click, and the code is inside a document.ready handler

Comment: @adeneo  , not working , i just wonder if there any way to make it without .closest !

Comment: Your code seem fine and should work. `closest` is the most efficient way of doing this.
I can not imagine why you would not want to use closest but you could also do `$(".myyyy-classs").parents(".General").first()`

Comment: The Post is Edited :D thanks all

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

After your update you will use .sibling() for that.

```js
$("#Template1").click(function(){
     $(".myyyy-classs").siblings(".General").html("Its woking")  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id='Template1'>Click Me</span>
<div class="General">
<div class="">hello</div>
<div class="">hello</div>
<div class="">hello</div>
</div>
<div class="myyyy-classs">hello</div>

<div class="General">
<div class="none">hello</div>
<div class="none">hello</div>
<div class="none">hello</div>
<div class="none">hello</div>
</div>
```

**Update 2**
The above one will select both .General.Secondly, if you want to select previous .General use .prev('.General') or/and for next you can use .next('.General').

Further .prevAll() and .nextAll() are the functions to select all the previous elements of match element or next elements relatively.

Comment: sorry mohammed , what about if the .General not the parent and it in the different div

Comment: Actually, I'm not getting you. What you want to select is myyy-classs with its parent that it .General. But if you want to select offset parent then use .offsetParent() function.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the .General is not a parent div but rather a sibling, so use this:

```
 $(".myyyy-classs").siblings(".General");
```

Please note that this will return all the siblings as an array, so if you want only the first one use this:

```
$(".myyyy-classs").siblings(".General").get(0);
```